# How to stop foreach loop when the row is blank

Tags: c#, excel, list

I've got code that imports a excel spreadsheet and get data from each column and row. The problem is it imports 120 rows even if there is only 19 row with data in. How do i stop importing if the next row is blank since i will not know how many lines each excel import may have. thanks

```
       DataSets = new ImportList().ImportFromExcel();

        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataTable table in DataSets[0].Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(row["LAST NAME"]?.ToString().Trim() ?? row.ItemArray[7]?.ToString().Trim());
            }
        }
```

Comment: break; read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break

Comment: So the problem is in `ImportFromExcel` which you don't show? You don't need to fix the symptoms if you have fixed the root of the issue.

Comment: If you want to fix the symtoms add: `if(row.ItemArray.All(o => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o?.ToString()))) break;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
    DataSets = new ImportList().ImportFromExcel();

    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataTable table in DataSets[0].Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (row["LAST NAME"]?.ToString().Trim() == string.empty) return; //OR BREAK
            list.Add(row["LAST NAME"]?.ToString().Trim() ?? row.ItemArray[7]?.ToString().Trim());
        }
    }
```

By testing the value of the cell before to add it and even exit the loop if needed (return or Break)

Comment: `return` is wrong

Comment: yes BREAK is the right keyword Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break;` in a `if` statement into the foreach loop

get a try.